# Template in a Template of a different types problem

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, compiler-errors

I have a template class called Temp, and it have a method takes an argument of the same type:

```
#ifndef TEMP_H
#define TEMP_H

template<class T>
class Temp
{
    public:
        T data;
        bool comp(T);
};
template<class T>
bool Temp<T>::comp(T data)
{
    return (this -> data < data);
}
#endif // TEMP_H
```

now I want to make an object of class Temp with type of pointer to another class called Foo.

```
Temp<Foo*> TptrF;
```

usually this is easy and for the method `comp`, I can do a specialization for this specific type `Foo*`, but I have to include the file `Foo.h` in `Temp.h`:

```
//Temp.h
#ifndef TEMP_H
#define TEMP_H
#include "Foo.h"

template<class T>
class Temp
{
    public:
        T data;
        bool comp(T);
};
template<class T>
bool Temp<T>::comp(T data)
{
    return (this -> data < data);
}
template<>
inline bool Temp<Foo*>::comp(Foo* data)
{
    return (this -> data -> val < data -> val);
}
#endif // TEMP_H
```

but the problem is that Foo class have an object of type `Temp<int>` and for this data member in Foo I have to include the file `Temp.h` in `Foo.h`:

```
//Foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
#include "Temp.h"

class Foo
{
    public:
        int val;
        Temp<int> Ti;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

this gives me in `Foo.h`:

> error: 'Temp' does not name a type

I tried to remove `#include "Foo.h"` from `Temp.h` and use a forward declaration instead like `class Foo;`, but it didn't work as I used the 'val' data member of class Foo in the `comp` function, and it gives me in `Temp.h`:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Foo'

and tried to remove `#include "Temp.h"` from `Foo.h`, and use a forward template declaration instead like `template<class T> class Temp;`,I thought this will work as I just need an object so I just want the compiler to know that I have a template class called Temp, but it also didn't work, and it give me in `Foo.h`:

> error: field 'Ti' has incomplete type `Temp<int>`

What should I do to make this code work?
`Temp<int>` and `Temp<Foo*>` do not contain each other as objects, so I believe this should work logically, or is it just one of the consequences of bad design.

Comment: My bad, I first though forward dec would solve it, only to see `this -> data -> val` afterward. The specialization `Temp<Foo*>` actually needs the _definition_ of `Foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to know what `Foo` is to compile `data->val`. So just move this to `Foo.h`

```
class Foo {
...
};

template<>
inline bool Temp<Foo*>::comp(Foo* data)
{
    return (this -> data -> val < data -> val);
}
```

Ref: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Go0-Zs

Comment: Yep! I didn't know that I can write a specialization of a method in another file, that was helpful Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the declaration of `comp` specialized with the type `Foo` in `Temp.h` and overload `operator<` in `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int val;
    Temp<int> Ti;
    bool operator<(const Foo& f) {
      return val < f.val;
    }
};
```

I'm just typing this in so hopefully this compiles.

Comment: This will compiles **but**, Unfortunately the overloaded operator will never called because it compares tow _objects_, and the comp function compare tow _pointers to object_, and as a result it will compare tow addresses of memory instead of comparing the val data member.
This will be helpful in case of template of type of another _object_, but not this one, template of type of _pointer_ to another object.

Comment: Ah, sure. Just change `const Foo&` to `Foo*` and `f.val` to `f->val` and it should be work fine.

Comment: man, are you sure of what you taking, because this operator will be called when comparing _object_ to pointer not _pointer_ to pointer, thus it will not be useful in this case too.